# Recursive Invocation: Poor Style?

Tags: c#, winforms, invoke

Below is a rather frightening pattern I sometimes use as a lazy way to do simple invocation.  This code makes me feel slightly guilty, even though I'm not sure why.  Is this horrifying? Reasonable? Going to blow up in my face later?

```
public void myMethod(object args)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            myMethod(args);
        }));
        return;
    }
    //Do Stuff
}
```

Comment: I prefer this way: Invoke(new Action<object>(myMethod)); //more readable I think.

Comment: @Homam: I feel like I'm doing things right when the name of the function `Invoke` matches the parameter type `MethodInvoker` so cleanly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very common means of making sure that a method is run using the UI thread's Synchronization Context.  There is nothing wrong with this.

(On a side note, it's the convention in .NET to use [pascal casing for methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229043.aspx), so I would change this to `MyMethod`.  Given that this question is about *style*, I feel this is worth mentioning.)

Comment: I think that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34386795/18192) Eric Lippert is saying that using async from the caller is better style.  Of course, that wasn't an option at the time you posted this answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is fine. Everything in one place. Easy to understand.